# How long does the baron buff stay on minions if the player leaves?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you run into your minions with your baron buff, you give them the baron buff, making them harder to kill and with a few upgrades.

Thing is, if you leave then leave them, how long will the baron effects stay on those minions before wearing off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a time-based thing. Really it's a certain distance. Once you get a certain amount of units away, it disappears off of the minions. It doesn't matter how long they had the baron buff.

Comment: Ok so as soon you leave the range they lose it?

Comment: Yes. I forget the number of units, but if you walk a certain distance away, then they lose it. That's why when you walk up near them that they suddenly gain the buff instead of it being a global thing. It's also why you want to push with the baron buff on the minions instead of playing passive.